# rounding issue - VFP

Tags: rounding, visual-foxpro

From Native VFP9 command window:

```
lyTotal_Revenue=16571.39
lyExcludeFromRent=1673.88
lnRentPercent=30
lnanswer=((lyTotal_Revenue - lyExcludeFromRent) * (lnRentPercent / 100))
?lnanswer shows 4469.253
```

That is the correct answer.

I have a report that has a field. The field's format expression is 9,999,999.99
The field's format options is Currency
The expression on the field is round(((lyTotal_Revenue-lyExcludeFromRent) * (lnRentPercent/100)),2)
Why does the report show $4,969.26

Comment: How would we know the values of lyTotal_Revenue, lyExcludeFromRent, lnPercent that you use in your report? We don't even know if they are memory variables, created in report or field values (without m. prefix, there is a chance that they may be field variables).

Comment: In report, I would temporarily create separate fields that show the values of  lyTotal_Revenue, lyExcludeFromRent, lnPercent (in details? Computed in summary?)

Comment: Hi Cetin. The 1st 3 lines of code that I posted represent the values of the 3 fields in the view being used by the report. I was trying to simplify the question but realized that was not going to get me the answer. I am going to answer my own question. If you do not agree with that answer please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized what the issue is. My report has the normal stuff meaning detail lines and a total line. Columns are Revenue and ExcludeFromRent. The total line is simply the sum of the detail lines. So I have the same fields on the total line but their Calculation tab has Sum on Report. I also have a summary page. That summary page does some math on the values from the total line. The math in pseudocode is Rent Revenue = (Total Revenue minus Total ExcludeFromRent). Then AmountToPay = Rent Revenue * (lnRentPercent / 100). So, the field in the summary section has an expression of round(((Revenue-ExcludeFromRent) * (lnrentpct/100)),2) and the Calculation tab has Sum on Report. What is wrong with this? Everytime a detail line gets processed the expression on the summary field is executed. That means I am rounding each detail row and adding that value to the summary field. What I did instead: I calculate the sum of the Revenue and ExcludeFromRent before calling the report and then execute the expression round(((Revenue-ExcludeFromRent) * (lnrentpct/100)),2) ONCE and place the value in a private variable. The expression for the summary field is the private variable and the Calculation tab says None.

John

EDIT: Any variable, array, for property etc are visible from within the report (because report is a command running technically within the same routine). ie: (discard the correctness of calculation I am doing, it is not, I know)

```
local lnTotalRevenue, lnExcludeFromRent, lnPercent
local array laRevenue[1]
select sum(Revenue) from myTable into array laRevenue

lnPercent = 30
lnTotalRevenue = round(laRevenue[1] - m.lnExcludeFromRent,2)
thisform.Tag = 'Rent Information'

report form MyReport ...
```

Within the report you have access to all those lnTotalRevenue, lnExcludeFromRent, lnPercent, laRevenue, thisform.Tag. This may be of great value sometimes.

Comment: That is a better solution. Then here is a tip: You could do the calculation before report and have it in any local memory variable, array, for property, whatever you like. All is visible from the report. I will edit your reply and add a sample there since here it would be a mess. Please mark your reply as an answer.

Comment: Cetin, I understand and thank you for the clarification. As best I can tell my earlier reply IS marked as an answer. If I am wrong please fix that for me and thanks again for all you do. John

Comment: I don't see it marked as an answer and I can't do that. I only see the vote I gave :) (and I don't know where you would do that, never asked a question)

Comment: I've been asking you questions for 20+ years and you have never asked a question. There is a story there. Again, Thanks for all you do, John

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stack-overflow contains a screenshot showing where to click when you (as the Question owner) want to accept an answer